# Setting imageView in cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

i am new to Swift and I have seen tons of guides on the topic. However in my case, it's working. I have a custom cell file:

```
class FileCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

func updateImage(name: String) {
    cellImage.image = UIImage(named: name)
}}
```

In the view controller I am using "willDisplay" function as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileCell") as! FileCell
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    if user.email.isEmpty {
        //cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "folder.png")
        cell.updateImage(name: "folder.png")
    } else {
        //cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "file.png")
        cell.updateImage(name: "file.png")
    }
}
```

where i try to change imageView in cell depending on the data incoming to cell. However, the images either don't display at all or cells are not showing up.

Thanks in advance for tips on what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not dequeue a new cell, since you already have one.
Just skip the first statement:

```
 // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileCell") as! FileCell
```

But one question: Why are you using the `willDisplay` delegate method? I would suggest to set up the cell in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileCell") as! FileCell
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.firstName.text = user.name // or something
    if user.email.isEmpty {
        cell.updateImage(name: "folder.png")
    } else {
        cell.updateImage(name: "file.png")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I thought I had to call willDisplay delegate to update the cells. It works fine, thanks again :)

Comment: @misi06 You should mark my answer as "answered" then, in order to show other users that the topic is solved.